# Time range query in Mongo db

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using django-nonrel and mongodb to develop app. I know that object id is start with a timestamp of the insertion time of object creation. So it's possible to do time range query based on _id field.

How can I generate a minimal object_id based on a given time in python or django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a much more pythonic version of the other answer here provided by OP, along with documentation:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import datetime

def datetime_to_objectid(dt):
    # ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
    # a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
    # a 3-byte machine identifier,
    # a 2-byte process id, and
    # a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

    timestamp = int((dt - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
    time_bytes = format(timestamp, 'x') #4 bytes
    return ObjectId(time_bytes+'00'*8) #+8 bytes
```

However, starting with version 1.6 of pymongo, it would be much more elegant to do the following:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

ObjectId.from_datetime(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import time

def get_minimal_object_id_for_int_timestamp(int_timestamp=None):
    if not int_timestamp:
        int_timestamp=int(time.time())
    return ObjectId(hex(int(int_timestamp))[2:]+'0000000000000000')

def get_int_timestamp_from_time_string(time_string=None): 

    # format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" like '2012-01-05 13:01:51'
    if not time_string:
        return int(time.time())
    return int(time.mktime(time.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

def get_minimal_object_id_for_time_string(time_string=None):
    return get_minimal_object_id_for_int_timestamp(get_int_timestamp_from_time_string(time_string=time_string))
```

I find the solution finally. hope it helps to others.